Difference in Time Zone data
I've entered into Ubuntu recently and got an issue with timezones.
I've got 1794 count in Centos Server of 7 version.
tzdata version
Command: rpm -q tzdata
Output : tzdata-2024a-1.el7.noarch

But I've got 454 count in Ubuntu Server of 24.04 version.
Command: dpkg-query -W tzdata
Output: tzdata  2024a-3ubuntu1.1

Because of this difference i'm facing timezone issue for my applications.
Please check and provide me some resolution.

I've seen currently that Asia/Calcutta timezone was missing in latest ubuntu 24.04
version where it was available in Centos 7 Version.

Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and use [code block]s to format them. And even if you must use screenshots for some reason, please don't include so much unnecessary whitespace borders around them.

The Asia/Calcutta timezone designation appear to have been moved into the tzdata-legacy package:
$ apt-file list tzdata-legacy | grep Calcutta
tzdata-legacy: /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Calcutta
tzdata-legacy: /usr/share/zoneinfo/right/Asia/Calcutta

with the primary tzdata package now providing only Asia/Kolkata to reflect the city's current official English spelling1:
$ apt-file list tzdata | grep Kol
tzdata: /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Kolkata

From /usr/share/doc/tzdata/NEWS.Debian.gz

tzdata (2023d-1) unstable; urgency=medium

    From 2023c-8 on the tzdata package ships only timezones that follow the
    current rules of geographical region (continent or ocean) and city name.
    All legacy timezone symlinks (old or merged timezones mentioned in the
    upstream backward file) were moved to tzdata-legacy. This includes the
    US/* timezones.

    Please install tzdata-legacy in case you need the legacy timezones or to
    restore the previous behavior. This might be needed in case the system
    provides timezone-aware data over the network (e. g. SQL databases).

 -- Benjamin Drung <bdrung@debian.org>  Tue, 02 Jan 2024 14:17:33
+0100


Installing the tzdata-legacy package should make the older Asia/Calcutta available on your system.

1. See for example Renaming of cities in India: Change in official English spelling

Presumably because Calcutta's name has been Kolkata for a while, and tzdata does have a /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Kolkata instead, so the old name is kept around in the legacy package for backward compatibility

@muru ah yes that makes perfect sense - thanks
